# How to unwritable /etc/resolv.conf in linux

Tags: networking, suspend, dns

whenever I suspend the system my changes in `/etc/resolv.conf` are set by default.

each time system loades changing a file is so tired.

There is each way to save my changes in `/etc/resolv.conf` ??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do. Why are you editing `/etc/resolv.conf`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: On Ubuntu, by deafult either systemd-resolved or NetworkManager manages your `resolv.conf`. You have to somehow disable either of those and install another application as DNS resolver to be able to edit it manually. This is one of the minor annoying things you have to be aware of in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

As Artur Meinild pointed out. The resolve.config file will be automatically altered by the installed network manager. (In which "NetworkManager" is one of them)

You can check by looking in your resolve.conf file

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
Generated by NetworkManager
```

There can be all sorts of network managers present on your system: Here is an example of the 2 main suspects:

If it's systemd you can manually change the DNS address in the systemd file
`/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. There you should comment out DNS or and fill in your desired service.

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

If it's NetworkManager, my main network manager, you can show the settings by executing
"$ sudo NetworkManager --print-config" in your terminal
Any DNS settings can be added in the shown file location:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and fill in

```
[main]
dns=8.8.8.8;
```

or in case you want it to leave the /etc/resolv.conf file alone

```
dns=none
```

In all cases you should restart the service or simply do it the windows way: reboot

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

**Extra update:** Your title suggests you only want a a writing block on the file. This is not common practice as such actions bypasses the Linux flow.

```
sudo chmod u-w /etc/resolv.conf
```

.. removes the write options of the file

Comment: none of those works :(

Comment: None? very strange. I've seen you've expanded the scope of the question. Maybe you can update your question a bit including the steps you've done so we can respond accordingly. It also seems strange that the only sanction you encounter is a DNS block. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chattr +i etc/resolv.conf
```

better done before making a network connection and I would not trust it too much.